# Copying HTML table row with JQuery prevents form validation event firing

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I have a JQuery plugin that binds the "change" event of all input and select elements contained by the last row of a table. When the event fires the handler creates a copy of the last row, inserts the copy then updates the event bindings. It seems to work for the most part. My problem, however, is that when the even fires and the new row is added, the form validation doesn't seem to fire except for the input element that triggered the "add row" event. If I leave the code exactly as it but remove the line that adds the new row, the form validation fires but the new row doesn't get added (obviously). Is there something I need to do differently when adding the row that will allow me to add the row and allow jquery validation to fire?

Here is a simplified version of the function in question:

```
(function (container) {
    var bindLastRowEvent = function (row) {
        row.find('input, select').on('change', lastRow);
    };

    var unbindLastRowEvent = function (row) {
        row.find('input, select').off('change', lastRow);
    };

    var lastRow = function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        if (row.next().length === 0) {

            var newRow = row.clone();

            newRow.removeClass("changed");
            newRow.find('input:text').val('');
            newRow.find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            newRow.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);

            unbindLastRowEvent(row);
            newRow.insertAfter(row); // removing this row allows validation behavior to be correct!!!
            bindLastRowEvent(newRow);
        }

    var gridAutoRow = function (table) {
        var row = table.find('tbody tr').last();
        bindLastRowEvent(row);
    };

    container.GridAutoRow = gridAutoRow;
})($);

$(function() {
    $.GridAutoRow('#someTable');
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if your copy code is triggering any errors?

Comment: You are passing your table in as the reference element. This doesn't know about the new rows you keep adding to it though, only the original ones. I suggest looking at this page that explains `Event Delegation`: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I see nothing in the question that has anything to do with the jQuery Validation plugin.  Please only use this tag when the question has to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: So when I originally posted it seemed to me that jquery validation was not firing. Upon further investigation what I've observed is that after changing a text box in the last row and then clicking the submit button, this in turn fires the "change" event on that textbox. At some point jquery validation fires to validate just the changed field. But for some reason the click event on the submit button does not fire unless I click a second time. That seems to be the real issue here. What am I doing to kill the processing of the click event that should in turn fire jquery validation on the form?